# Requires PHP version 5.3.0

Tags: plugins, php, functions

When I try to install "Background Manager" plugin I am getting this error "The plugin "Background Manager" requires PHP version 5.3.0 or better, but version 5.2.17 was detected".  Could anyone suggest me how to get rid of this error?  Or else suggest me the plugin that suits my requirement.

Requirement

Display a random image as the website background at each visit or as a timed slideshow.

Comment: Upgrade your very outdated PHP version. That’s what the message suggests. There is no way around it.

Comment: @toscho what about the people who visits my website having older version of php?

Comment: Your website uses PHP, not your visitors. Even PHP 5.3 is already out of date. Get the current PHP 5.4 version.

Answer (score 2):

You're getting this because you're running PHP 5.2 on your server. The plugin requires PHP 5.3. If it did not do this check, you would get an error when it tried to use a PHP 5.3 feature.

I won't recommend a plugin as that would be offtopic and result in the question being closed ( hint: edit that out of your question ).

The fix, is to upgrade to PHP 5.3, or even better, PHP 5.4. PHP 5.3 is already nearing end of life, and PHP 5.2 is significantly slower than 5.3, insecure, and has bugs. 5.5 is due out soon.

For reference PHP 5.2.4, the minimum needed version, was released in February 2007, at least 6 years ago.

**Contact your host or server administrator and demand an update. *It is long overdue***